# Response in encoded format

Tags: node.js

I have written an API using node.js, in that i request for a url ad i will return the response in json format

Following is my receiving part:

```
try{
      proxyRes.on("data", function(chunk) { //Capture API response here---revisit
      body = chunk.toString();
      console.log("Inside data=" + (body));
      });
    } catch(err){
       console.log("errrr=" +err.stack);
    }
```

But its printing as some encoded string(I think so) like below:

```
�1� 
]d���!��w���^2���_#YP>3'y˥�p)�H�����S]}X;�yR�F�8
```

So tried for `base64` decoder package, but its not working, the same is printing.

Also when i hit the url in browser i am getting the following json response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
  }
}
```

But in my code i am receiving encrypted code. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `proxyRes.setEncoding('utf8');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by modifying the response,

I changed:

```
return res.json({
            "error": {
                "code" : 404,
                "message" : "invalid_grant",
                "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
            }
        })
```

TO:

```
res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
res.end(JSON.stringify({
            "error": {
                "code" : 404,
                "message" : "invalid_grant",
                "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
            }
        }, null, "\n"));
        return;
        //return res.redirect('/login');//signin
    }
```

It works fine now..